# Why does my create-react-app console.log twice?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, use-state

I'm just making a simple recipe fetching app using the create-react-app setup, but when I tried logging the response it logged it twice. I went backwards and deleted code until it stopped happening and for whatever reason it starts when I use the state hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const APP_ID = '092fa53f';
  const APP_KEY = '6fcf8c591c129cc3d01aefbda0d8a4d8';
  const recipe_url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log('test')}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should have removed the 3 unused `const`s - now you need to rotate those credentials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does useState cause the component to render twice on each update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578158/why-does-usestate-cause-the-component-to-render-twice-on-each-update)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is on purpose, it's part of [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) (specifically to [detect unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
>   can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
>   This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

If you remove the `StrictMode` element from `index.js`, you'll see the output only gets logged once:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Note that in strict mode this only happens in *development*, not in production.

Comment: This is potentially dangerous (potentially) and people may want to consider the answer I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77026108/63043