# Why is functional component executed twice if useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wonder why does calling React useState causes functional component to be executed twice.
Please see an example.

Instantiating a Dummy component with a following body:

```
const Dummy = () => {

  console.log('[Dummy] starting');

  return (
    <p>Dummy</p>
  )
};
```

Outputs:

```
[App] start
[Dummy] starting
```

But for a following body:

```
const Dummy = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  console.log('[Dummy] starting');

  return (
    <p>Dummy</p>
  )
};
```

Console shows:

```
[App] start
[Dummy] starting
[Dummy] starting
```

Common parent code for both cases:

```
const app = () => {
  console.log('[App] start');
  return (
    <Dummy />
  );
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521734/why-does-my-create-react-app-console-log-twice

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that one answers my question perfectly.