# why am i getting the same output twice in console in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVaax.png)

In the above image(link to image:"enter link description here") "ProductList"(a component of React project) is giving correct output and the only output should be of "ProductList" in console but i don't know why am i getting same output with "VM55" as well, and what is this "VM55".Please help me, i am stuck to this for past 20 days  and this is my 3 react project where i am facing the same issue.

Comment: google strict mode and double rendering

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing to worry about!
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521734/why-does-my-create-react-app-console-log-twice)

This only happens in development mode.
**Please do not remove strict mode**

In the future you can check with profiler tab if to component really rendered twice (or more) [react profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html)

Answer (score -1):

Go to index.js file and delete  <React.StrictMode>

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <>
    <App />
  </>
);
```

Comment: Why do you recommend removing StrictMode? This is a developer tool to help catch bugs. It very well may be causing the double render, but why remove it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/13627973

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).