# component is rendering when the state value is not changing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the below code, the component will be rendered once. Because the state value does not change when I click on the button.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  const handler = () => {
    setCount(1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log("rendering")}
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={handler}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the browser console, the output is after clicking the button three times

```
rendering
```

Now what will happen to this code,

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  const handler = () => {
    setCount(2)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log("rendering")}
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={handler}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I click on the button the first time, the component will be rendered. so, total rendering should be 2 times including initial rendering. When I click the button 2nd time, the component should not be rendered. because state value is not changing, no new reference should not created then. But why it will render a total of 3 times when I click the button 2nd time?

In the browser console, the output is after clicking the button three times

```
rendering
rendering
rendering
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VM1550 installHook.js:1860 logging as a double line in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372878/vm1550-installhook-js1860-logging-as-a-double-line-in-the-console)

Comment: My best guess would be that the fact that `handler` is a new reference causes a rerender despite state not changing.  You can verify this by trying `const handler = React.useCallback(() => {setCount(1);}, []);`

Comment: What version of react you are using @noob_developer?

Comment: codeblock 1&2 are the same or am i missing something?

Comment: I am using the 18.2.0 version of react @ClusterH